# fragment.onCreateView causes null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

So i am using fragments and trying to wire on click listeners on them.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
      //  View contentView=super.onCreateView(inflater,null,savedInstanceState,R.layout.layout1);
        startButton= (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
```

This is the XML for the button

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Time"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#1e497c"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

This is my Exception

02-28 16:49:57.162  14375-14375/com.example.listviewandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL

```
EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewandroid/com.example.listviewandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.fragment.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:43)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Its obvious its not able to find button or something is happening which i am not able to figure out. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

simply use this in your `onCreateView`

```
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
    startButton= (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    return contentView;
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `getView()` until `onCreateView()` returns since it is the method in charge of creating said view. You should change your code to

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
        startButton = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Or alternatively, override `onViewCreated()` and implement your Button setup in that method (using `getView()`.

Answer (score 2):

This line makes no sense:

```
startButton= (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
```

You don't have a View yet, you are still creating it..

In stead you can do this:

```
 startButton= (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Or wait until the onCreateView method returns the actual View you just created and then you will be able to get a reference of the view using the "getView" method after onCreateView returns the view..

Hope it Helps!

Regards!